# Simple PHP include with Grunt (or alternative)

Tags: php, gruntjs, jekyll, yeoman

I'm modifying Yeoman's "webapp" build and customizing it to match my needs.

I'd like to do simple includes of repeated patterns across the site like the header and footer. I dabbled with Jekyll a bit but I'm concerned it's a little too complex for my needs.

I'm currently using PHP includes but this isn't jiving well with Grunt.

**Is there an easy alternative to PHP includes or a method of having Grunt run PHP? What is best practice?**

Answer (score 0):

If your really confused with Jekyll, just take one hour to go across the website and you'll get super powers. This is plain html for templates + a little liquid for logic, and nothing more.

I really find it more simple than all the Yeoman, Grunt things.

My two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I know neither Yeoman nor Grunt, but like David Jacquel already said in his answer: making global headers and footers is **dead simple** with Jekyll.

You need a **layout file**, which is just a HTML file with placeholders that goes into the `/_layouts` folder *(see [Directory structure](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/))*:

I'll call it `default.html`, so the complete path is: `/_layouts/default.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
    YOUR HEADER HERE
    </div>

    <div>
    {{ content }}
    </div>

    <div>
    YOUR FOOTER HERE
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

- `{{ content }}` is where the content of your actual pages will be inserted.
- `{{ page.title }}` refers to the title of the page *(needs to be defined in each page)*.

Then, you need to create an actual page. You can use either HTML or Markdown:

### Either `/index.html`:

```
---
layout: default
title: page title here
---

Some <strong>text</strong>
```

### ...or `/index.md`:

```
---
layout: default
title: page title here
---

Some **text**
```

- The `---` part in the beginning is [YAML Front-matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/).
- The line `layout: default` refers to the `/_layouts/default.html` file created earlier.
- The `title: ...` line will be inserted into the `{{ page.title }}` placeholder in the layout file.

The end result, no matter if you use HTML or Markdown, will be created as `/index.html` and look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
    YOUR HEADER HERE
    </div>

    <div>
    Some <strong>text</strong>
    </div>

    <div>
    YOUR FOOTER HERE
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

If you want to make the layout more modular, you can also move the custom headers and footers into separate [include files](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes).
Change the layout file to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% include header.html %}

    <div>
    {{ content }}
    </div>

    {% include footer.html %}

</body>
</html>
```

The two `{% include ...` lines refer to files in the `/_includes` folder, so you can create `/_includes/header.html` and `/_includes/footer.html` and put the desired HTML into those files.